# WFS layer not adding correct layer

Tags: qgis, layers, wfs, vector-layer

[image]
I wanted it to add the "boxes" as shown in the bottom half of the picture. However, it comes out as shown in the top half.
I'm using 3.28
Sorry for the lack of knowledge in regards to the termonology, I'm VERY new to QGIS

Comment: It looks like your WFS isn't specifying the geometry type so QGis is saying "I don't know" when asked what type your layer is - the layer will probably still display correctly though

Comment: Adding to Ian's comment, Features in a WFS may not have any geometry associated with them, rather than them not specifying it correctly.   Can you give the WFS service URL

Comment: You bet I can. 
URL:https://services.drift.kortinfo.net/kortinfo/services/Wfs.ashx?Site=Aalborg&Page=kortHjemmeside&BBox=550168.734081881,6320300.86072593,560410.0614982481,6327616.094594764&UsePageEpsg=1
The URL works in version 2.26.3

Comment: The `LatLongBoundingBox` for some of the featuretypes is incorrect; shouldn't see any values above +/- 180.  Looks like some are incorrectly using the bounds of the native CRS (in that CRS). `ugis:TL289460` (Bygninger (GeoDanmark)) is one of these.  `Planzoner` is correctly configured and displays

Comment: May be a deeper issue though.  QGIS sends a request like : ` https://services.drift.kortinfo.net/kortinfo/services/Wfs.ashx?Site=Aalborg&Page=kortHjemmeside&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.0.0&TYPENAME=ugis:TL289460&MAXFEATURES=1&SRSNAME=EPSG:25832&OUTPUTFORMAT=GML3` which is valid, but the server returns an error

Comment: Alright, thank you all for helping out